# Developer mode for the VSCode plugin marketplace is not available

Tags: plugins, google-play

After downloading the code from the official website of VSCode - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode.git, and installing the corresponding packages, if you execute the command "./scripts/code.bat" and then try to access the plugin marketplace through the new window that pops up, you may face an issue where the marketplace cannot be accessed. This was not a problem in older versions of VSCode. How can the latest version be updated to support the plugin marketplace?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIXg9.png)

Enable the plugin marketplace feature.